# Своя конфигурационная секция в App.config

Tags: c#

Требуется реализовать свою секцию в App.config. Имеется какое-то небольшое консольное приложение, при первом запуске, пользователь вводит логин и пароль, и они отправляются в конфиг в свою секцию userinfo, к примеру. Данные не будут меняться, не буду добавляться, нужно будет лишь доставать их с конфига. Предложите, пожалуйста, реализацию с хоть каким-то разъяснением что, почему и зачем .

Comment: [Практическое руководство. Создание пользовательских разделов конфигурации с помощью класса ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

App.config  - это обычный xml файл и работать ты с ним можешь как с xml документом с помощью XDocument или XmlDocument. Любая из этих библиотек  прексасно сможет прочесть этот файл. Главное - все изменения в файле вступят в силу только после перезапуска приложения.

```
public void CustomAppConfig()
    {
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
        var config = XDocument.Load(path);
        var xElement = config.Element(XName.Get("configuration"));
        xElement?.Add(new XElement("myCustomSection", new XElement("User", "PasteUSerName"), new XElement("Password", "PasteUserPassword")));
        config.Save("C:\\Your application path\\App.config");

    }
```

Чтение по принципу обратному:

```
public void CustomSectionRead()
    {
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
        var config = XDocument.Load(path);
        var xElement = config.Element(XName.Get("configuration"));
        if (xElement != null)
        {
            var myConf = xElement.Element(XName.Get("myCustomSection"));
            if (myConf != null)
            {
                foreach (var node in myConf.Elements())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Минус мой. Тревога "Не является ответом" тоже моя. Тянет на комментарий, не более. Просили же - пример работы с секцией, могли бы расписать красиво и подробно и получить заслуженные плюсы.

Comment: Не понятно, как этот ответ вообще связан с кастомной секцией

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо».  Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтёте полезными. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/252712)

Comment: @iluxa1810 А где тут фраза "спасибо"?